# How to write intersect query for data coming from 2 different oracle databases

Tags: oracle

I have two oracle databases, Database 'A' and 'B'. They have some common columns like task_ID , description, status etc. which represents similar information. 
Now I want to write a query which should do the intersection of 'A' and 'B' for those common columns.

Writing a shell script to do this is the only option/best option?
Is there a way of doing this in oracle query itself.

I have gone through other solutions over the internet but most of them are intersection examples for same database.

What is the best way of achieving this?

Comment: Have your dba create a [db link](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/managing-database-links) between the two

Comment: Thank you for responding. Is there any other way of doing this on my own as developer (As DBA route seems difficult due to project structure. )

Comment: Not unless you have rights to create a db link, which you probably don't

Comment: Thank you. I will proceed with this option.